# (dart) replaceAll method in a string in a loop (cypher)

Tags: string, dart, encryption, cypher, cs50

I'm attempting to do CS50 courses in dart, so for week 2 substitution test i'm stuck with this:

```
    void main(List<String> args) {
  String alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  String cypher = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';
  int n = alphabet.length;

  print('entertext:');
  String text = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: utf8)!;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    text = text.replaceAll(alphabet[i], cypher[i]);
  }
  print(text);
}
```

**Expected result:** abcdef = qwerty

**Actual result:** jvmkmn

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm a total beginner by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you at first substitute the letter `a` with the letter `q`, but when `n = 16`, you will replace all the letter `q` with the letter `j`. This is why your `a` is turned into a `j`, and so forth...

Best of luck to you :)

Comment: Oh, i'm too dumb for programming. Gonna get good though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the (very direct and) safer approach would be:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  String alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  String cypher = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';

  assert(alphabet.length == cypher.length);
  
  // Pattern matching any character in `alphabet`.
  var re = RegExp('[${RegExp.escape(alphabet)}]');

  print('enter text:');
  String text = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: utf8)!;
  
  // Replace each character matched by `re` with the corresponding 
  // character in `cypher`.
  text = text.replaceAllMapped(re, (m) => cypher[alphabet.indexOf(m[0]!)]);
  print(text);
}
```

(This is not an *efficient* approach. It does a linear lookup in the alphabet for each character. A more efficient approach would either recognize that the alphabet is a contiguous range of character codes, and just do some arithmetic to find the position in the alphabet, or (if it wasn't a contiguous range) could build a more efficient lookup table for the alphabet first).

Comment: Seems like a much better and more readable answer. I've started learning to code a month and a half ago, used to be a dog groomer. All this stuff still feels too complex for me. But i'll try to study your answer and understand how it works! Thanks!